# Problem in accessing JBoss Repository through Nexus Repository Manager

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

We are using Nexus Repository Manager as our Corporate Repository Manager.
The nexus repository manager was linked to JBoss Repository with following remote url.

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/
Today when I checked the nexus, i saw following message for JBoss
In Service - Remote automatically blocked and unavailable.

This message generally comes when your firewall is not allowing you to access the JBoss url. But the nexus is able to access maven central repository, which indirectly tells that there is no problem in the Proxy.

The same message is also shown for following urls
Name                 URL                                            Type/Policy
java.net - Maven 2   (http://download.java.net/maven/2/)            proxy/Release
java.net-m1          (http://download.java.net/maven/1/)            proxy/Release
Apache Snapshots     (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/)      proxy/Snapshot

Please reply if any one has idea about it.

Comment: There is a related open bug (https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/CENTRALSRV-10).  But has proxying stopped working with the old url? I could download, for instance - http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/HTTPClient/HTTPClient/0.3-3/HTTPClient-0.3-3.jar

Comment: I do not know much about proxy repository so do not know whether the proxying stopped in nexus because of change of url.

Comment: It was problem with the firewall authentication. I changed the username and password and it started working. But still there are some Release repository which are not working like (http://download.java.net/maven/2/). Any quick suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maven Central is NOT relocated, only has some new means preventing repository "scraping". It will still serve up artifacts if requested by maven using *absolute* paths. So, for Maven Central, you should use the URL http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ as it's the only one working. As you noted, the search.maven.org (where scrapers are redirected) is totally different beast, not usable with Maven nor Nexus as remote repository.

You should rather check why your Nexus thought Maven Central is not reachable. Do you have some internal (maybe transparent) HTTP Proxy between host running Nexus and outer world (Internet)? Or some other means preventing Nexus reaching out? Also, it might be network issue (brownout, blackout) of the network.... and Nexus just blocked proxying to prevent connection leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following items:

1. Under **Server** check that the http proxy is set and authenticated properly
2. Under **Repositories** check that the **Public Repositories** group has the JBoss repository included in the *Ordered Group Repositories* list under the *Configuration* tab